# Select a value on a drop down field with then pre selects values in a multi-select field

Tags: javascript

I have two fields. I am dynamically pulling in values for each field. I can not hard code any of the data because it its changing.

With javascript i want to select a value with the 1st single select drop down field. on click i want the second one to update with the matching ids.

ex (again values are dynamically getting pulled)

**field 1- single select drop down list**
Name (text displayed) - Id (value submitted)
Fruits - 1
Vegetables - 2
Sweets - 3
Meat- 4

**Field 2- multi sect list box**
Name (text displayed) - Id (value submitted)
Apple -  1
Carrot-2
Ice Cream - 3
Hamburger- 4
Orange- 1
Steak -4 
Chocolate- 3
Raspberries -1

**Desired outcome:**
If the user selects Fruits from field 1
then the field 2 should pre select apple, orange, Raspberries (because they all have the same id of 1)

I am dynamically pulling the data from salesforce in c# Page_Init 
data binding it to the fields

```
<asp:Panel CssClass="form-group" runat="server">
<label id="Field1" class="control-label" for="Field2" runat="server">
<asp:DropDownList ID="Field1" ClientIDMode="Static" 
onchange="myFunction(event)" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" />
```

```
<asp:Panel CssClass="form-group" runat="server">
<label id="field2" class="control-label" for="field2" runat="server"> 
</label>
<asp:ListBox ID="field2" CssClass="form-control" SelectionMode="Multiple" 
ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
</asp:Panel>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(e) {
        document.getElementById("field2").value = e.target.value
    }
 </script>
```

I originally had this jquery in when i was just updating a single select drop down field. it is still selecting 1 value not all the values with the matching ids

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. What exactly is your question? You've described your desired behavior, but have posted no code and no error messages. What have you tried, and what is not working?

Comment: Hello Matt ,Originally  I had two single select drop downs and i was able to update the second field  with:  function myFunction(e) {
            document.getElementById("field2").value = e.target.value
        } but i have had to account for multiple matching ids. and i am not sure how to do that

Comment: Could you edit your question and post a code sample please so we can better understand what is happening? Please include the HTML definition of the dropdowns, the JS used to fetch the data and change the drop down values, and the data being returned from the server. Thanks

Comment: hopefully this helps clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up looking up a similar request and edited it to be dynamic values not hard coded

```
<select name='field1' id="field1">
<option value="1">Fruits</option>
<option value="2">Vegetables</option>
<option value="3">Sweets</option>
<option value="4">Meat</option>
</select>

<select name='field2' id="field2" multiple >
<option value="1">Apple</option>
<option value="2">Carrot</option>
<option value="3">Ice Cream </option>
<option value="4">Hamburger</option>
<option value="1">Orange</option>
 <option value="4">Steak </option>
  <option value="3">Chocolate</option>
   <option value="1">Raspberries </option>
 </select>

 var foodsToSelect = $("#field1").val();
 var foods = document.getElementById( 'field2' );

 for ( var i = 0, l = foods.options.length, o; i < l; i++ )
 {
 o = foods.options[i];
 if ( foodsToSelect.indexOf( o.value ) != -1 )
 {
  o.selected = true;
}
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jw8rugse/2/